# Euclidean distance from vector features for radiotracking data in R

Tags: r, distance, polyline-creation, multi-polygon

I have a radiotracking dataset (ca 5000 rows) like this

```
Animal     Date     Time Latitude Longitude
Pepe 21/12/2020 23:00:28 52.25938  15.50511
Pepe 21/12/2020 19:00:15 52.26251  15.52726
Pepe 21/12/2020 09:00:19 52.26175  15.51602
Pepe 21/12/2020 03:00:13 52.25384  15.51395
Pepe 22/12/2020 23:00:37 52.21680  15.54818
```

And I have different shapefiles representing different features: the road network is represented as a polyline layer, the forest layer is a multipolygon layer.

I was wondering how to SIMPLY calculate in R the euclidean distance:

- from the nearest road
- from edge of the forest patch; moreover, I would like to attribute increasing **positive** values if points are located farer outside a forest patch, and increasing **negative** values if points are located deeper inside a forest patch (like in the image below)

[image]

The final result should be added as a new column like this, for further analyses in R

```
Animal   Date     Time   Latitude  Longitude Dist_road Dist_edge
Pepe 21/12/2020 23:00:28 52.25938  15.50511  34.54     56.21
Pepe 21/12/2020 19:00:15 52.26251  15.52726  46.78     -34.67
Pepe 21/12/2020 09:00:19 52.26175  15.51602  21.43     -21.59
Pepe 21/12/2020 03:00:13 52.25384  15.51395  23.45     89.90
Pepe 22/12/2020 23:00:37 52.21680  15.54818  90.34     -38.43
```

After converting the log-lat coordinate system in a metric (i.e., UTM), how can I perform such spatial analyses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following function computes the distance from points to a polygon. Putting stuff like this in functions should always be done. Note the use of a cast to MULTILINESTRING to compute the distance to the polygon edge, and the use of `st_intersects` to negate the distance for any points inside the polygon:

```
edge_distance <- function(pts, poly){
    d = st_distance(pts, st_cast(poly,"MULTILINESTRING"))
    inside = lengths(st_intersects(pts, poly)) != 0
    d[inside] = -d[inside]
    return(d)
}
```

Here's my test code. For sample data I'll use an `sf` polygons object included with the package and generate 20 points diagonally across the bounding box:

```
# use first row as our forest:
forest = st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))[1,]

box = st_bbox(forest)
xp = seq(box[1], box[3], len=20)
yp = seq(box[2], box[4], len=20)
tracking = st_as_sf(data.frame(xp, yp),
            coords=1:2, 
            crs=st_crs(forest))
```

Now compute signed edge distance for those 20 points:

```
tracking$D = edge_distance(tracking, forest)
```

and plot using `tmap`:

```
library(tmap)
tm_shape(forest) + tm_polygons()  + tm_shape(tracking) +tm_symbols(col="D")
```

Showing negative values inside the polygon and positive ones outside.

You don't really need to convert to UTM since `sf` will work in spherical geometry distance, which might be better for your application.

[image]

Comment: It seems exactly what I need. Unfortunately, I cannot compute the function because I cannot find `st_perimeter` and I'm not able to install its R package. I'll wait until January 9th when I'll switch PC. Meanwhile another question: I've never used `sf` package, so should the arguments within `edge_distance()` be objects of sf class?

Comment: I may have messed up, replacing an `st_cast` to MULTILINESTRING by st_perimeter without testing. Idiot me. st_perimeter is from lwgeom and computes the length of the perimeter. Let me edit...

Comment: Yes I messed up. I wrote it originally using a cast, then thought "ooh, there's st_perimeter, I should use that", which I edited my code to do, and then tested it, but stupidly forgot to re-load the function definition so it was still using the old one with the cast! Fixed now with sample data generation included as a bonus for you. Its all `sf` class objects.

Comment: Absolutely no problem! I'm sorry to bother you but I tried both with my data and your test code and the same error appeared `Error in st_distance(pts, st_cast(poly, "MULTILINESTRING")) : 
  st_distance for longitude/latitude data only available for POINT geometries`. This is quite strange since both mine and yours dataset are POINT geometries (SF class). Is it perhaps linked to my 'not the last' version of R?

Comment: Possibly related to the sf version (me: 1.0.9).  I can do st_distance between lat-long polygons no problem. Try this in a clean R session (needs no library calls): `nc = sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) ; sf::st_distance(nc$geom[1], nc$geom[20])`

Comment: I tried the function with another PC and with another `sf` version (1.0.8) and it works perfectly! Thank you @Spacedman